# SQL Server service and agent account permission changes do I need to restart service to take effect

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication, sql-agent-job

I have a SQL Server service account: `domain\sqlservice`.

This account is running both SQL Server service and SQL Server Agent Service.

This account has read/write permission to a file share: `\\fileserver\Path1`, and from the SQL Server and SQL Server Agent jobs, we are able to write to this folder path using the service account (using `master..xp_cmdshell`. `xp_cmdshell` is enabled).

This permission got removed by mistake, now we have added it back.

I can use the service account `domain\sqlservice` to browse to `\\fileserver\Path1` and create files and folders (using Windows Explorer), but SQL Server and SQL Server Agent jobs still could not.

I have restarted the SQL Server Agent service (I believe this is account used to access the file share when running the SQL Server Agent jobs).

But it still failed to access the path - I get an access denied error.

I think I will need to restart the SQL Server service to fix this issue (waiting for my maintenance window now).

I want to understand it better, can someone give me some hint on why SQL Server Agent job is related to the SQL Server services running account? And what is the relationship between SQL Server Agent job service account and SQL Server service account? Are we still utilize this account to access fileshare defined in the SQL Server Agent job?

Thank you all very much

Comment: Double check that SQL Server is definitely still running under that service account, as well as which account has now received permissions to the share. The permissions for `xp_cmdshell` depend on whether the session has `sa` rights, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#xp_cmdshell-proxy-account. Quite why you are using `xp_cmdshell` is a different question: it has major security implications, and should probably be converted into a SQL Agent job written in Powershell.

Comment: The relationship between the engine service account and the agent service account is only that they are both service accounts. They are set (typically by the DBA) during SQL Server instance installation on the machine, and are independent of each other. If you are using a domain account as the agent service account, you can set its NTFS permissions as you can for any other domain account. If it is running as network service, you need to set permissions for the machine account.

Comment: It looks like the issue is resolved after a couple of hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Charlieface’s comment explains the reason:

> Double check that SQL Server is definitely still running under that service account, as well as which account has now received permissions to the share. The permissions for xp_cmdshell depend on whether the session has sa rights, see learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/…. Quite why you are using xp_cmdshell is a different question: it has major security implications, and should probably be converted into a SQL Agent job written in Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it takes time for the service account to get updated.
So I rerun the task in 10 hours
and task runs fine.
So I guess you have two options.

1. wait for the token or something expire and renewed.
2. you can restart the service.

Comment: By default a Kerberos ticket expires after 10 hours